# Number of ways to pick the balls to paint in red color?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, combinations, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

***How to optimize the solution using DP ?***

***Problem Statement***:

> We are given 3 integers **N, K, Q** where,
>
> ***N*** = number of balls initially in the bag(numbered from 1 to N and all are white-colored),
>
> ***K*** = number of turns,
>
> ***Q*** = The number of balls we pick at each turn from the bag.
>
> We are asked to return an *array of size (N + 1)*, where ***arr[i]***
>   represents the number of ways we can pick the balls such that at end of ***Kth*** turn exactly **i** number of balls should be red-colored.

***The way we are supposed to pick the balls***:

> At each turn we have to pick exactly Q balls from the bag randomly, and paint
>   white ones to red, and leave red ones as it is, then replaces them
>   back into the bag.
>
> **This means at any instance(turn) all the N balls(numbered from 1 to N) are present in the bag**.

Constraints:

```
 1<=N<=100
 1<=K<=100
 1<=Q<=N
```

**Example**:

```
**INPUT**:
N = 3, K = 2, Q = 2, 
Let the balls are numbered as 1, 2 and 3.

All possible ways to pick balls in K = 2 turns:

pick1 pick2
(1,2) (1,2) = 2 red balls 
(1,3) (1,3) = 2 red balls
(3,2) (3,2) = 2 red balls 
(1,2) (1,3) = 3 red balls
(1,2) (2,3) = 3 red balls
(1,3) (1,2) = 3 red balls 
(1,3) (2,3) = 3 red balls
(2,3) (1,3) = 3 red balls
(2,3) (1,2) = 3 red balls



so, we have 
0 ways to paint exactly 0 ball red in K number of turns,
0 ways to paint exactly 1 ball red in K number of turns,
3 ways to paint exactly 2 balls red in K number of turns & 
6 ways to paint exactly 3 balls in K = 2 number of turns.

**OUTPUT**: 
arr[] = [0, 0, 3, 6]
```

***Solution:***
I tried to solve this problem as a ***combination(C(n,r))*** problem.
And solved it recursively as follows:

```
 // utility function to calculate C(n,r)
  void calculate_CnR(vector<vector<long long> > &C){  
    for(int n = 0; n < C.size(); n++){
        for(int r = 0; r < C[0].size(); r++){
            if(n >= r){
                if(n == r || r == 0) C[n][r] = 1;
                else if(r == 1) C[n][r] = n;
                else    C[n][r] = (C[n - 1][r - 1] % (1000000007) + C[n - 1][r] % (1000000007)) % (1000000007);
            }
        }
    }
}


// main method
// B = number of balls left to paint red
// r = number of red balls present in bag currently
// w = number of white balls present in bag currently
// K = number of turns left
// Q = number of balls need to pick at each turn
// C = to access C(n,r) value in O(1) time

long long num_ways(int B, int r, int w, int K, const int &Q, const vector<vector<long long> > &C){

    // base case
    if(K == 0){ //turns over

        if(B > 0)
            return 0;
        else if(B == 0)
            return 1;

    }

    // decide maximum number of white balls we can pick
    long long max_ = min(B, Q);

    long long ways = 0;
    for(int white_picks = 0; white_picks <= max_; white_picks++){

        int red_picks = Q - white_picks;

        if(red_picks <= r && white_picks <= w){  // red/white_picks num_balls must be present in the bag to pick.
            ways += (
                        ((C[w][white_picks] * C[r][red_picks]) % 1000000007) 
                            * 
                        (num_ways(B - white_picks, r + white_picks, w - white_picks, K - 1, Q, C) % 1000000007) 

                    )   % (1000000007);
        }
    }

    return ways;
}



   int main(){

    // C[n][r] represents nCr 
    vector<vector<long long> > C(101, vector<long long>(101, 0));
    calculate_CnR(C);


    int tests = (cin>>tests, tests);
    while(tests--){
        int N = (cin>>N, N);    // num balls
        int K = (cin>>K, K);    // turns
        int Q = (cin>>Q, Q);    // num of balls picked at each turn

        vector<long long> ways(N + 1, 0);

        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
            ways[i] = num_ways(i, 0, N, K, Q, C) % (1000000000 + 7);
        }

    }

    return 0;
  }
```

> With this code, even on input **N = 50, Q = 3, K = 6** this is giving TLE(time limit exceeded error)

So I think somehow DP(dynamic programming) can save us the computation time, but I am having a hard time figuring out **how repeated subproblems** exist here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply memorization.

```
// main method
// B = number of balls left to paint red
// r = number of red balls present in bag currently
// w = number of white balls present in bag currently
// K = number of turns left
// Q = number of balls need to pick at each turn
// C = to access C(n,r) value in O(1) time
```

For this purpose we can ignore parameters that are constant for the run.

- C and Q are constant so we can ignore them.
- B+r is constant so we can ignore one of them (I've picked to ignore B)
- r+w is constant so we can ignore one of them (I've picked to ignore w).

So you have a space of r, K. If you keep track of what configurations you've already solved during a run you should be able to have a polynomial complexity and beat the time limit.

Another way to think about it, the intermediate state is how many ways there are to take K turns and have r red balls.

Comment: Thanks, @sorin.
And what about, 
num_ways(i, r, w, K, Q, C) and 
num_ways(j, r, w, K, Q, C) where i != j. 
Is there a possibility of these 2 having the same subproblem?

Comment: @rawat This is what you do in the main and it invalidates the observation that B+r is constant, so to make it work you need to clear the table. You do recalculate a lot of stuff. In the last step you only consider results if they have the right number of red balls. If you make it work to consider all values, then you won't need the loop in main (remove an N from the complexity). This would also be the DP solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider a simple example where repeated subproblems occur. Take `Q = 2`; the below doesn't show all of the recursive calls made, just enough to see that some are made with the same arguments.

- Suppose `w = 4`, `r = 1` and `K = 3`.

  - Call recursively with `w = 3`, `r = 2`, `K = 2` when 1 more white ball is painted red.

    - Call recursively with `w = 1`, `r = 4`, `K = 1` when 2 more white balls are painted red.
  - Call recursively with `w = 2`, `r = 3`, `K = 2` when 2 more white balls are painted red.

    - Call recursively with `w = 1`, `r = 4`, `K = 1` when 1 more white ball is painted red.

So, the subproblem where `w = 1`, `r = 4` and `K = 1` is solved at least twice by the recursive algorithm. If memoization or dynamic programming is used, the solution to this subproblem will only be computed once and then reused.

Comment: Thanks, @kaya3.
And what about, 
num_ways(i, r, w, K, Q, C) and 
num_ways(j, r, w, K, Q, C) where i != j. 
Is there a possibility of these 2 having the same subproblem?

Comment: @rawat No, it's not possible in that case, because `B + r` is invariant, and the two examples have different `B + r`.